# Is the order of iteration on a standard angular for loop guaranteed?

Tags: angular, angular5

Is the order of iteration of the standard angular 2 loop guaranteed i.e. will the order of execution of each loop always be the same?

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];

for (let value of array) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

will the result always be 
1
2
3

Answer (score 1):

It will always follow the iterable object order in case of `for...of`.

See: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)